# Why is it acceptable to cite unpublished works?

Tags: citations

If an article, theorem, etc. is unpublished, presumably the work is only available to people who track down the author and get a draft copy. Today we have arXiv and can find many preprints on the Internet, but people have been citing unpublished works longer than arXiv has been around. It seems like an unscrupulous author could claim anything he wants, cite an unpublished work that doesn't support his claim (or even one that doesn't exist), and get away with it unless the bad claim is caught in the review process.

I suppose the reviewers could ask for a copy of the cited work, but I recently saw a citation that was just "private communication 1981" for a paper published in 1985, and that could easily have been a phone call where no record could be provided to a reviewer.

I've never published anything myself, so maybe I'm unaware of a part of the review process that is meant to catch this, but what prevents authors from making bad citations of unpublished works?

Comment: How is this different from citing an obscure book? Just because the content isn't easily available, doesn't mean it can't be cited.

Comment: @Mast What do you mean by an "obscure book"? I assume that your obscure book went through a refereeing process and so it is, most obviously, completely different from an **obscure** phone call and in fact from **any** phone call. It is crucial not to write nonsense such as "private communication 1981" in the references (in other places it is basically acceptable, we can live with that).

Comment: @JohnB why do you assume that "book went through a refereeing process"?

Comment: @DanM. Why do you assume that you can call it a book otherwise?

Comment: @JohnB There's nothing inherent with books that implies it should be refereed. Of course, books published by a reputable publisher should undergo copyediting process, but that's not peer review. Though obscure books published by a proper publisher in most countries should at least have a legal deposit available; so not completely unobtainable from a third party, compared to unpublished private communications etc..

Comment: There are three things to consider here: often the publishing process takes long in mathematics, I had at least couple papers for which the review took 1+ year and then it took over two years since they were accepted till they appeared. Once a paper is accepted, there is almost no difference between it and a published one, even if it is still "unpublish". (2) Very often, people find about new results at conferences, and very often, if the speaker is good and gives enough details, I can get a good understanding of the proof from the talk. (3) This is not always possible, but often I try

Comment: @JohnB I don't think that matters. If you disagree, just make your point and explain where I was wrong isntead of asking personal questions. Any qualified librarian at your institution or public library will tell you about what kind of books qualify for reliable sources in academia, e.g. http://ncu.libanswers.com/faq/168497

Comment: .... to understand the results I am using, no matter if it is published or just a pre-print. Sometimes I find mistakes (even in published works); and often I can see if the proof is correct or not, sometimes I even learn new tools or ideas. If I do check the proof carefully, I trust myself more than an unknown reviewer, and then the publishing status of teh paper is irrelevant.

Comment: Simple: By citing someone you acknowledge their contribution. You acknowledge that their ideas/contributions were made and important to your work. It does not matter whether these ideas are formally published or just transmitted personally, e.g. in emails. And for lesser contributions there is always the acknowledgements section.

Comment: This is too basic for an answer, but it may be helpful to think about. Bad citation is lying. It is fundamentally no different to say "Professor Bob told me that the moon is cheese" than "I took lunar samples and my mouse confirmed they are cheddar." What stops lying? Honesty. Professionalism. Not wanting to say something stupid. Not wanting to be caught because it sounds stupid. Not wanting to be caught in reproduction attempts.

Comment: For the record, I have contacted someone who was listed in a "private communication" citation before and asked for an explanation of the cited content, and they were happy to oblige. While that's not always possible, its not as if that entire class of source material is definitively unobtainable. And as others have pointed out, if you got an idea from someone else, you have to credit them for it, even if it was private communication.

Comment: Whether it's under the purview of a reviewer or not, it is the prerogative of the end user to vet citations. What is unacceptable is ever taking anything at face valve. - If your cite is a phone call I'm going to call bs and move on.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

You seem to be interpreting citations as a way of proving something by appeal to authority.  That is not what citations are.  A citation is a way of giving appropriate credit to the originator of an idea and pointing the reader to the explanation of that idea.  ***Not* giving credit to the person who gave you an important original idea is unethical, whether that idea has been published or not.**

Citing a "personal communication" related to a mathematical fact (for instance) does not eliminate the need to prove that fact.  Appropriate usage would be to write something like "the following was communicated to me by X. Y. [personal communication]", followed by (for instance) a theorem statement **and** its proof.

Note that if something is in a technical report or on arXiv, it is not *unpublished*.  People *publish* blog posts, novels, and Youtube videos.  ***Published* and *peer-reviewed* are completely different things and it's wrong to conflate them.**

Comment: I interpret citations in two ways: 1. to give credit to the originator of an idea, and 2. to provide further reading to the reader (e.g. for details not pertinent to the current paper, but which the reader might be interested in). Maybe the second point is me assuming too much, but it seems that every other form of citation satisfies both points.

Comment: Zaen is correct.  Please edit accordingly.  Citing a work which will be published in the future is a way of providing further information to the reader.  Private communications may be in that category.

Comment: Very good points; I have edited the answer to incorporate them.

Comment: Somewhere here on Academia I've read that YouTube videos are not appropriate source for citation, which kind of conflicts with your answer.

Comment: Whether something is an appropriate source of information and wheather you should cite it are two different things. The problem with citing YouTube videos is not that you shouldn't cite YouTube if you got something from there, but that you shouldn't be getting your information from YouTube.

Comment: A YouTube video surely beats "personal communication" as a source, and a YouTube video of an academic conference could be a decent source.

Comment: The bigger problem with citing YouTube videos is that they vanish too easily.

Comment: Also, a citation doesn't mean that you regard the cited work as the objective Truth. One might even cite results which have since been proven to be wrong, if you need them as an example, or you need to discuss the shortcomings of the methods they used and show how to improve them. Because even "wrong" results can be useful as building blocks to build something better (or to demonstrate the shortcomings of a method in favor of another), and if someone already did the groundwork, why not use it? Or of your work is about disproving an old theory, you have to cite the old theory you are refuting.

Comment: @IanSudbery Whether something on YouTube is useful or not is not a property of YouTube itself.

Comment: In addition to giving credit to the source of information, regardless of whether the source has been pubished or not; citing unpublished material or even personal communicaitons provides the reader with a clue where to search next. If an author uses method X for her work, and I am interested in this method, a citation to an unpublished source or personal communication provides me at least the name of the source. I can use this name to look for further material, or contact the source.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica the proper way would be to web.archive the video first and then cite that. Otherwise - I see no fundamental problem with that. There are papers citing 4chan, since some anon solved some decades old math problem.

Comment: All these things are super context dependent. But _when_ people say that you shouldn't cite Youtube, its because they don't believe that its a suitable source of information, but because there is anything inherently wrong with citing youtube. We spend a lot of time telling our undergrads not to cite wikipedia, or youtube etc because we don't want them trusting these as sources when more authoritive sources for _their_ needs are available. I'd probably still cite a conference talk without a published abstract as pers comms,  even if there were a youtube video.

Comment: YouTube is a publication platform. Like any other platform, the author of the work is more important than the platform. As an example, Lawrence Lessig is a recognized expert in copyright and he posts videos about copyright occasionally on YouTube. It seems perfectly appropriate to cite to one of his YouTube videos for a point on copyright, even if only to give him proper credit.

Comment: @vsz While law and social sciences are notably different from the hard sciences, I have frequently cited to prior work that I disagreed with to explain why I believed they were wrong or no longer relevant. Citing sources to attempt to refute them is absolutely commonplace in legal scholarship.

Comment: Doesn't this depend on the field? For example in law, a citation typically *is* an appeal to authority.

Comment: 'You seem to be interpreting citations as a way of proving something by appeal to authority.' ...well actually they kind of are. This is why we cite peer-reviewed literature, they indicate a minimum level of scientific rigour and scientific method. Maybe different for non-science fields but anecdotal evidence is not really acceptable

Answer (score 52):

**What's the alternative?** I can only see two:

- Don't write the text. This would also mean you have something worth sharing, but are not sharing it. This goes against the purpose of publishing in the first place.
- Write the text, but don't cite it. That's plagiarism.

Since the alternatives are undesirable, it's acceptable to cite unpublished works.

Comment: 'Don't write the text. This would also mean you have something worth sharing, but are not sharing it. This goes against the purpose of publishing in the first place.' this seems like a logica non sequitur. It isn't ones to share (it is someone else's) and needs to go through peer review first.

Answer (score 28):

An [answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/148407/33210) by [David Ketcheson](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/81/david-ketcheson) highlights the importance of giving credit for ideas as a reason for citing unpublished works.

Another reason for citing unpublished works can be [*grey literature*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey_literature). The linked Wikipedia article describes the history of *grey literature* coming out of World War II, when the Allies produced a large amount of nuclear research that was not formally published, but still scientific important.

In my personal experience in applied ecology, *grey literature* can be an important source for management decisions and data. For example, a wildlife preserve manager might do controlled burns every 5 years based upon their wildlife preserve's local monitoring program. But, they would not formally publish their work as an article. Instead, they might summarize their work as part of a report that lacks peer review. However, a researcher studying fire ecology might describe the wildlife preserve's management as part of a peer review article or describe trends at the preserve.

More broadly, nuance is key to understanding what is acceptable to cite. First, different academic fields have different general expectations for how to cite non-peer reviewed science and journals usually have a distinct citation style (e.g., inline vs reference section). Second, a nuanced view is important for what is being cited. Citing facts, observations, and applied choices differ from citing conclusions.

Last, to answer your final question, **what prevents authors from making bad citations of unpublished works?** Nothing. But, a nuanced view of peer-reviewed articles helps here. Just because something is peer-reviewed, it is not infallible. Additionally, I've had authors make *bad* citations of my published works. I've joked I sometimes learn new things about my research by reading work that cites it.

Answer (score 5):

A complement to the good answers already here:

Giving people credit for the ideas they bring to you, by whatever means available even if not ideal, signals to possible future collaborators that it's safe to bring other ideas to you. Safe in the sense that you're not just going to let people assume you're the source of the idea.

If widespread enough, the practice of citing by whatever means available signals that it's safe to bring ideas to *the community* without worrying about first getting proof that it's yours. That's established to some extent in the scientific community, and we all should contribute to keep it going.

There's a lot to be said about the advantages of exposing preliminary results, doubts, even half-formed ideas to colleagues, even those who are otherwise strangers. That's most of the point of conferences.

Answer (score 4):

What does harm research progress is quoting **any** literature without having read it or dropping citations for the bang of it. There, sloppiness or bad faith are disguised under the shine of a DOI or ISBN. Anything that is not peer-reviewed, and reported as such, will be looked at at face value and put in perspective: let writers write critically, let readers read critically.

As others point out very well down this post, the crux is doing justice to the others' work, conscientiousness and creativity, in accordance with their own job specifications.

Off-note. Once you mention you are new to publishing, among countless resources, you might find it interesting to read the science pages that the British newspaper The Guardian dedicates, with some regularity, to [peer review and scientific publishing](https://www.theguardian.com/science/peer-review-scientific-publishing). 
It is sometimes useful to have journalists looking at science.
These ones among and along others.

Answer (score 4):

*(To add to the already good answers. I'll assume math, since you mention "theorem" and "arxiv", but this probably applies way more in general)*

What would "get away with it" mean here? Publishing is not a magical process that endows the published article with an indelible aura of perfection for the ages. Publishing is just the (usual, normal, common, accepted) way of disseminating one's research. If someone's research is wrong, this will be known rather sooner than later.

Papers are most often refereed by people who are experts in the topic, so getting away with claiming something outrageous from an obscure source will not get you very far. The more important the journal, the more true this is.

Also, research is not something that happens in a vacuum. There is a community. If you are doing something that is not related to anything anybody cares about, and you publish in bad journals, you can probably "get away" with almost anything. But a normal researcher cites people, talks at conferences and meets those people, themselves and their work become known. Those "mysterious preprints" form the past were available to anyone who asked (you would send a letter to the researcher and get a copy, that was standard back then). So, the people who cared about those preprints did have them.

Answer (score -1):

I think if a work is not unpublished, there is no such thing as "cite", it is merely mentioning. But I do think it is important to do so.

First, when you make a scientific argument in your work, you always need evidence and support. Mentioning unpublished work tells readers that what you are talking about is true, and they will keep it in mind and go to validate it when you actually publish it.

The second is that to show others you are the first one to make these discoveries, but you have not published it yet. This is important in academia as well.

Comment: "if a work is not unpublished, there is no such thing as cite" <- I think you may have included more negatives than you intended to here.